# Alternate TFS Web Interface

Tags: tfs, web, wsdl

I know TFS has a web server that gets installed with it, and that's great. I know it integrates very tightly, and very well with Sharepoint, and that's also great.

What I'd like to know though, is since the WSDL's for TFS are public, essentially making the API to send and receive data from it public as well; are there any alternate, non-Microsoft interfaces to TFS that provide most or all of the functionality, with consumer-driven enhancements, such as charting, or reporting solutions not found out of the box?

I've searched the almighty Google and Bing, and they are proving very difficult to find answers from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own solution using SharePoint Enterprise edition and a combination of Excel Services reports and SQL Server Reporting Services reports; A SharePoint solution is the closest you'll find to something.

You can use the [TFS SDK](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/TfsSdk/) and object model to create your own application, but most people don't go very deep because Microsoft's Web Access tool is a capable client tool for most teams.  There were also major improvements just released in the new TFS 2012. In fact Web Access started out as a 3rd party tool and there are some ways you can extend it.

There is one app I know of off the top of my head that has a web interface to TFS that is very simple; it can be found at http://techdayskanban.codeplex.com

There is also an example of extending the TFS Web Access at http://tfstimesheet.codeplex.com

Codeplex is a good place to check around because it is open source.

A commercial example of a product that extends Web Access can be found at http://urbanturtle.com though It seems you are looking for something more stand-alone.

Comment: Perfect Ryan, actually that's what I was looking for, I was just looking to see if it had been done yet, to any extent, mostly for presentation purposes to show that its a possibility if needed.